Evaluate $\int \cos 2\theta \ln(\frac{\cos \theta+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta- \sin\theta})d\theta$
Evaluate $\int \cos 2\theta \ln(\frac{\cos \theta+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta- \sin\theta})d\theta$.
My attempt:
I converted the part inside $\ln()$ to $\ln\left(\frac{1+\sin 2\theta}{\cos 2\theta}\right)$ then put it as t but I can't proceed further, should i try by parts in the final eqn with dt or is there a shorter method?

Mathematica:  $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (\cos (\theta )-\sin (\theta ))+\log (\sin (\theta )+\cos (\theta
))+\sin (2 \theta ) \log \left(\frac{\sin (\theta )+\cos (\theta )}{\cos (\theta
)-\sin (\theta )}\right)\right)$$

Try $\tan(\theta)=x$

HINT
Another possible approach:
\begin{align*}
\int\cos(2\theta)\ln\left(\frac{\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta)}\right)\mathrm{d}\theta & = \frac{1}{2}\int\cos(2\theta)\ln\left(\frac{1 + \sin(2\theta)}{1 - \sin(2\theta)}\right)\mathrm{d}\theta\\\\
& = \frac{1}{4}\int\ln\left(\frac{1 + \sin(2\theta)}{1 - \sin(2\theta)}\right)\mathrm{d}(\sin(2\theta))\\\\
& = \frac{1}{4}\int\ln\left(\frac{1 + u}{1 - u}\right)\mathrm{d}u\\\\
& = \frac{1}{4}\int\left(\ln(1 + u) - \ln(1 - u)\right)\mathrm{d}u\\\\
& = \frac{1}{4}\int\ln(1 + u)\mathrm{d}u - \frac{1}{4}\int\ln(1 - u)\mathrm{d}u
\end{align*}
then apply integration by parts to each integral.
Can you take it from here?

Note that $$\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta\right) = \frac{\cos \theta + \sin \theta}{\cos \theta - \sin \theta} $$
So your integral is same as evaluating the integral $$\int_{}^{} \cos 2\theta \ln \left(\tan \theta\right) d \theta$$
Substituting $\tan \theta = x$, your integral becomes:
$$ \begin{equation} 
\int_{}^{} \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2} \ln x \cdot \left(1+x^2\right) dx \\ 
= \int_{}^{} \left(1-x^2\right)\ln x  dx \\ 
= x \ln x -x - \int_{}^{} x^2 \ln x dx + C\\
\end{equation}$$
The last integral can be finished up nicely using IBP, and then you can do reverse substitution to get the desired result

Too long for comment, but here's how it would go roughly$$I=\int \cos 2\theta \ln\left(\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta\right)\right)\,d\theta$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta = t\implies d\theta=dt, 2\theta=2t-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$I=\int \cos \left(2t-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \ln\left(\tan(t)\right)\,dt$$
$$\cos(-x)=\cos x, \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\sin(x)$$
$$\implies \cos \left(2t-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\cos \left(-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2t\right)\right)=\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2t\right)=\sin(2t)$$
$$I=\int \sin(2t) \ln\left(\tan(t)\right)\,dt$$
Integrating by parts and applying the standard identities, we end up with
(skipping over the steps, you will be using double angle identity of cosine and sine the usual $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1, \tan^2x+1=\sec^2x$)
$$I={\ln\left(\tan\left(t\right)\right) - \frac{\ln\left(\tan^{2}\left(t\right) + 1\right)}{2}} - \frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(t\right)\right)}{ \left(\tan^{2}\left(t\right) + 1\right)}$$
Back substitution,
$$I={\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta\right)\right) - \frac{\ln\left(\tan^{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta\right) + 1\right)}{2}} - \frac{\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta\right)\right)}{ \left(\tan^{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta\right) + 1\right)}$$
